# How can I display dynamically ItemsControl like Items of a parent ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

I have two tables in a database : sections table and exams table. A section (in sections table) has one or more exams (in exams table).

Foreach section in sections I want to show the section name and under the name the exams of this section in an ItemsControl. This image may explain it more.

[image]

So for it I'm getting the list of the sections  from the database and I use it as  ItemsSource of an custom template of an ItemsControl; An ItemsControl will display the sections an each section will have under itself an ItemsControl displaying this section's exams.

Here is the template of the sections ItemsControl

```
    <Style TargetType="ItemsControl" x:Key="ListSectionsItemsControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>

        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="{Binding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <ItemsControl Name="AnalysesItemsTest" Style="{DynamicResource ListAnalysesItemsControl}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="3" Background="White"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>



    </Style>
```

For the exams i created also a template of ItemsControl

```
  <Style TargetType="ItemsControl" x:Key="ListAnalysesItemsControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>

        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="2" Background="White"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>



    </Style>
```

In my Xaml i create an ItemsControl which uses the template style of sections ItemsControl like this :

```
<ItemsControl Name="SectionsItemsControl" Style="{DynamicResource ListSectionsItemsControl}"/>
```

and I get successfully the sections names.

But I can't display the section's exams.

I try to attribute a name for the exams ItemsControl (in the style template of sections ItemsControl) so that i can  define for it the itemsSource in code behind but i can get it in the code behind. zI also try to define an ItemsSource but nothing also.

Please how can do it ?
Thanks for your helps.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything there sets the itemssource of either itemscontrol. How does the inner itemscontrol know it's supposed to know where it picks the exams up from?

Comment: I define the ItemsSource of Sections ItemsControl in the code behind. And it's what I'm trying to do with the Exams ItemsControl.